# Kafka Streams - one on two does not operate - wrong partition assignments

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In an application of my company, in order to apply a few transformations to 2 group of messages called LIVE and PRE-MATCH, we create 2 Kafka Streams, one for each of these groups.
Both of these streams are started correctly, however one of them which is always the second created on a time-based order, does not operate any change: by this I mean that it doesn't consume anything from the start topic.

An analysis of the logs, shows that there must be some issue with the configuration of topics and partitions:

```
2018-09-26 11:36:59,963 [INFO ] [] [StreamThread-2] [o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator] - Setting newly assigned partitions [] for group Union
2018-09-26 11:36:59,963 [INFO ] [] [StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator] - Setting newly assigned partitions [betgenius.integralfeed.live-0] for group Union
```

As you can see in the portion of log above, the StreamThread-1, associated to LIVE feeds, gets correct assignment of partitions mapped to the correct source-topic; StreamThread-2, which is associated in this case to PRE-MATCH feeds, seems to receive a partition assignment to an empty source-topic and is actually the one that does not operate.

If i artificially force the PRE-MATCH stream to be created before the LIVE one, the situation is reversed.

The code used to create the 2 streams is absolutely identical, I just change the start topic and the end topics.

Is it possible that there are not enough resources available on my configuration of Kafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to provided logs, seems you use the same groupId `Union` for both Kafka streams, but they should be unique for each stream. so make sure you provided different values for settings property `application.id`.

`application.id` - identifier for the stream processing application, must be unique within the Kafka cluster.

Comment: I confirm that i am using the same `application.id` for both streams: I though that this property identified the whole application, not the single stream and that's why i used the same id... I will try to change it and let you know

Comment: that is the problem, `application.id` should be different for different streams. the idea of this property: if you run the same app on multiple servers, specific stream will have the same `application.id` value on all servers (so stream flow will be in the same consumer group), but different streams should have unique values. e.g. first stream has value `firstAppId`, second - `secondAppId`, and if you launch your app on another server, still streams will have  `firstAppId` and `secondAppId` values.